# SQL join simple problem

Tags: sql, join

This is simple SQL JOIN question  and my solution works while trying with sample data but when i do the same with huge data, it fails.

I have two table
**tbl1**

```
a   b
0   10
1   2
4   5
2    2
```

Another table **tbl2**

```
a    c
1   22
2   18
10   9
98   8
```

Now i want final table like this

```
a    b     c

0   10
1    2     22
2    2     18
4    5
10         9
98         8
```

What i did is:
 
1) `temptbl = select a from tbl1 UNION select a from tbl2;`
2) `valueA = temptbl left join tbl1 on a` 
3) `valueB = temptbl left join tbl2 on a` 
4) `inner join valueA and ValueB on a`

My solution works on small data when i try it locally, but while running it on server, left join produces some random data (steps 1 works, but after step 2, it does not work). Can somebody help me on this? AM i doing wrong? Are there any other solution

Please note, value in column **a** is unique in both the table.

Comment: Which database are you using? This looks like yet another full outer join scenario, and different solutions apply to different DBMSes.

Comment: Can you post your full SQL please?

Comment: Actually i am working on COSMOS. It's Microsoft internal data storage/query system. Basically all the syntax are similar to SQL(MS SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in pieces:

```
-- Pick out records whose "a" values are in T1
SELECT T1.a, T1. b, T2.c 
FROM   T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
ON  T1.a=T2.a

UNION

-- Add records whose "a" values are NOT in T1
SELECT T2.a, NULL 'b', T2.c
FROM   T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE T1.a = T2.a)
```

Comment: +1 for being portable without FULL JOIN. But I would have gone with FULL JOIN, since it is stated as SQL Server

Comment: This does not work too. COMOS does not support complex queries(the secord part of UNION is not supported). Isn't there any simple way by just using JOINS??

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT coalesce(tbl1.a, tbl2.a) as a, /* one of them will be non-null */
       tbl1.b,
       tbl2.c
FROM   tbl1 FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2
ON     tbl1.a = tbl2.a
```

If your database doesn't support the `FULL JOIN`, you can `UNION` together a `LEFT JOIN` for each of the tables. A `LEFT JOIN` with only tbl1 on the "left side" will not yield records where only tbl2 has an `a` value.

---

**Edit:** Per the OP's request here's the equivalent as a `UNION` -- since apparently this database doesn't support @DVK's good suggestion of an anti-join:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       NULL as c
FROM   tbl1
UNION
SELECT a,
       NULL as b,
       c
FROM   tbl2
```

Comment: You don't need to union two left joins - you can union an outer join with anti-join (see my answer)

Comment: coalesce is not supported in COSMOS. I can only use joins.

Comment: I tried finding LEFT JOIN for both tables then doing the union but i got an error saying left schema column and right schema column does not match.

Comment: @chota, can you use `isnull` or `case-when-then`? I suppose it doesn't matter if your database doesn't support the full join. I'm adding a left/union/left approach above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT all.a, b, c
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM tbl1 UNION SELECT a from tbl 2) all
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl1 on tbl1.a = all.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.a = all.a
```

Comment: this does not get the value of 'a' present in tbl1 but not present in tbl2